# Create resource at runtime for Web Api controller

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api2

My application is multi tenant right now and I have a class that looks up which settings to use based on which tenant is logged in. So I have some code in every controller that essentially looks like this.

```
[RoutePrefix("api/client/{id})]
public class ReportsController : ApiController
{
    ILogHandler _logHandler = new LogHandler();
    private processor _processor = null;

    public ReportsController(IProcessor Processor)
    {
        _processor = Processor;
    }

    [Route("")]
    [HttpGet]
    [EnableQuery]
    public IHttpActionResult Get(Guid id)
    {
            //Some pseudo code here to get some settings for a client
            var settings = clientSettings(id);

            //investigate the settings
            if(settings.CanDoSomething())
                var qi = _processor.process();
            return Ok(qi);
    }
}
```

I look up some settings and decide to do some stuff. My problem is every single controller has to do the lookup process but what I'd like to do is have the object already be there and scoped to the correct client.

I tried using Owin middleware and putting the object in the Owin environment but I guess it's to early in the pipeline and I don't know what the value of the `Id` is in the middleware.

I also have autofac and I've looked into using [multitenant](http://docs.autofac.org/en/latest/advanced/multitenant.html#asp-net-integration) but that appears to be more geared toward resolving specific dependencies per tenant or giving tenants access to certain controllers. What I'm after is every tenant gets one of these objects each request but it just needs different setup.

Comment: Where does the `id` come from? The url/querystring? Or POST data? Or does it do either depending on which controller method it is calling?

Comment: Right now I have all my routes set up to send it as part of the url. So all my controllers follow the pattern of /api/client/{clientid}/{resource}

Comment: I've been trying to avoid a hacky regex solution. I know there are functions available like getRoueData. They just always seem to not be available in the places I need to use them like middlewares

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you've tried to implement this using Owin Middleware. I would think that it would work, but maybe you were looking for an easy way to get the `id` field, which isn't possible. The problem with Owin middleware is that it works at a really low level: you only get a `IDictionary<string, object>` which contains all of the information you need to do stuff (in your case, getting the `id` from the query string; in Web Api's case, getting a whole bunch of stuff). A minor abstraction over this is the `OwinMiddleware` class; it presents the information from a web request in an object of type `IOwinContext`. Using Autofac, you can register your middleware with it so it can inject dependencies into it. Given that information, we can create an owin middleware that grabs the `id` from the query string and sets it on an injected `ClientSettings` instance:

```
public class IDParserMiddleware : OwinMiddleware
{
    private ClientSettings Settings;

    public IDParserMiddleware(OwinMiddleware next, ClientSettings settings)
        : base(next)
    {
        Settings = settings;
    }

    public override Task Invoke(IOwinContext context)
    {
        string[] query = context.Request.QueryString.Value.Split('&');
        string id = null;
        foreach (string keyvalue in query)
        {
            if (keyvalue.StartsWith("id=", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
            {
                id = keyvalue.Substring(3); // right after "id="
                break;
            }
        }

        Settings.ID = Guid.Parse(id);

        return this.Next.Invoke(context);
    }
}
```

You can then register this with Owin like so:

```
IAppBuilder app; // you get this from Owin code like WebApp.Start()
var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
builder.RegisterType<IDParserMiddleware>();
//...
var container = builder.Build();

// This will add the Autofac middleware as well as the middleware
// registered in the container, like IDParserMiddleware
app.UseAutofacMiddleware(container);
// Finally, register Web Api. We do this last so that our middleware
// can run before it and set the ID property.
app.UseAutofacWebApi(config);
app.UseWebApi(config);
```

More information about that is in [this Autofac doc](http://docs.autofac.org/en/latest/integration/owin.html#dependency-injection-in-middleware).

Finally, you can have `ClientSettings` injected into your controller's (or any class's) constructor:

```
public ReportsController(IProcessor Processor, ClientSettings settings)
{
    _processor = Processor;
    _settings = settings;
}
```

Due note that I haven't tried this, but from what I've read this should work. Good luck!

Comment: I just realized that code is looking at the query string, whereas for you it isn't part of the query string; it is just the main url. So, you'll just need to modify that parsing code to find it from `context.Request.Path` or `context.Request.Uri`.

Comment: It's not a bad solution to the problem I just wish I didn't have to resort regex. seems like id like to have something that the controller provides like a `GetRouteData()`

Comment: The problem is that all of this is occurring before Web Api even gets a chance to look at it. Last time I looked into hooking into Web Api itself so I could use simpler classes and methods, I could not find a solution without doing it at the controller level. So unless someone, or you, finds a way to do it in Web Api, you are stuck parsing the URL like above. Truthfully, I hope someone can come up with a better solution. This really is ugly and too low level to work with, and I too would love to use the easier Web Api classes. But for now, it seems like it is the only reasonable solution.